# genetic algorithm string guess

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am trying to understand how to implement a genetic algorithm and wrote a simple string guess.  I am having trouble understanding why this solution is not working.

I believe that my problem is in my populating my new generations?  The newest generations do not seem to have improved fitness values.  I am also not sure if I am doing the crossover and mutation rates correctly.  Any help would be really appreciated!

```
POP_SIZE = 300;
CROSSOVER_RATE = 0.7;
MUTATION_RATE = 0.01
GENESET = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"
target = "Hello World"
RAND_NUM = random.random()

def generateBasePopulation(population_size):
    population = dict()

    for _ in range(POP_SIZE):
        gene = generateParent(len(target))
        population[gene] = 0

    return population


def generateNewPopulation(population, population_size):
    newPopulation = dict()

    while(len(newPopulation) <= POP_SIZE):
        child_one, child_two = crossover(child_one, child_two)
        child_one = mutate(child_one)
        child_two = mutate(child_two)


    newPopulation[child] = 0
    newPopulation[child_two] = 0
    return newPopulation



def assignFitness(population):
    for x in population:
        population[x] = getFitness(x)


def generateParent(length):
    genes = list("")
    for i in range(0,length):
        random_gene = random.choice(GENESET)
        genes.append(random_gene)
    return(''.join(genes))

def getFitness(candidate):
    fitness = 0
    for i in range(0, len(candidate) - 1):
        if target[i] == candidate[i]:
            fitness += 1
    return(fitness)

def mutate(parent):
    gene_index_to_mutate = random.randint(0, len(parent) - 1)
    mutation_value = random.choice(GENESET)
    genes = list(parent)
    genes[gene_index_to_mutate] = mutation_value
    return(''.join(genes))

def crossover(parentA, parentB):
    if(RAND_NUM < CROSSOVER_RATE):
        random_index = random.randint(0, len(target))
        parentASlice = parentA[:random_index]
        parentBSlice = parentB[random_index:]

        return (parentASlice + parentBSlice), (parentBSlice + parentASlice)
    return parentA, parentB


def chooseChild(population):
    fitnessSum = sum(population.values())
    pick = random.uniform(0, fitnessSum)
    current = 0
    for pop in population:
        current += population[pop]
        if current >= pick:
            return pop


def main():
    population = generateBasePopulation(POP_SIZE)

    targetNotFound = True

    while(targetNotFound):
        assignFitness(population)
        if target in population:
            print("target found!")
            targetNotFound = False
        if(targetNotFound):
            tempPopulation = generateNewPopulation(population, POP_SIZE)
            population.clear()
            population = tempPopulation
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the `generateNewPopulation` function.

#### `child_one` and `child_two` are referenced before assignment

You need two individuals from the population to perform the crossover. There are several selection algorithms, but just to give an idea you could start with a form of [tournament selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_selection):

```
def extractFromPopulation(population):
    best = random.choice(list(population.keys()))

    for _ in range(4):
        gene = random.choice(list(population.keys()))
        if population[gene] > population[best]:
            best = gene

    return best
```

Here the selection pressure (`range(4)`) is fixed. It's one of the parameters you've to tune in a real case.

Now we have:

```
def generateNewPopulation(population, population_size):
    newPopulation = dict()

    while len(newPopulation) <= POP_SIZE:
        child_one = extractFromPopulation(population)
        child_two = extractFromPopulation(population)

    # ...
```

The code still doesn't work because

#### new individuals aren't inserted in `newPopulation`

Just indent the two lines:

```
newPopulation[child] = 0
newPopulation[child_two] = 0
```

(they must be part of the `while` loop)

The revised `generateNewPopulation` function follows:

```
def generateNewPopulation(population, population_size):
    newPopulation = dict()

    while len(newPopulation) <= POP_SIZE:
        child_one = extractFromPopulation(population)
        child_two = extractFromPopulation(population)

        child_one, child_two = crossover(child_one, child_two)
        child_one = mutate(child_one)
        child_two = mutate(child_two)

        newPopulation[child_one] = 0
        newPopulation[child_two] = 0

    return newPopulation
```

---

#### The `crossover` function cannot be based on a fixed `RAND_NUM` value

Delete the `RAND_NUM = random.random()` assignment and change the `crossover` function to use a new random value at each call:

```
def crossover(parentA, parentB):
    if random.random() < CROSSOVER_RATE:
        random_index = random.randint(0, len(target))
        parentASlice = parentA[:random_index]
        parentBSlice = parentB[random_index:]

        return (parentASlice + parentBSlice), (parentBSlice + parentASlice)

    return parentA, parentB
```

Also the code doesn't correctly perform single point crossover since schemata of the second parent aren't preserved.

---

You could change many details to improve performance but, as a starting example, it's probably enough as it is (...it works).

Average number of generations to find a solution is about `158` (average on `200` runs).

---

EDIT (thanks to *alexis* for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505872/genetic-algorithm-string-guess/47528236#comment82033020_47528236))

`MUTATION_RATE` is unused and a mutation always happens. The `mutate` function should be something like:

```
def mutate(parent):
    if random.random() < MUTATION_RATE: 
        gene_index_to_mutate = random.randint(0, len(parent) - 1)
        mutation_value = random.choice(GENESET)
        genes = list(parent)
        genes[gene_index_to_mutate] = mutation_value
        return ''.join(genes)

    return parent
```

This fix is particularly important if you keep the roulette wheel selection algorithm (`chooseChild` often doesn't converge without the fix).

Comment: I believe in the OP's code the children are meant to be selected with `chooseChild()`, which is defined but unused (and selects with probability proportional to the fitness, which will have to drive the improvements).

Comment: @alexis You are right, I missed that function. Probably in the OP's code the children are meant to be selected with `chooseChild()`. Anyway the suggested changes should remain valid.

Comment: @alexis Thank you for the comment, a further issue (related to the `mutation()` procedure) was present but it emerged only trying the `chooseChild()` function.